# Ограничить выдачу SuggestView конкретным городом

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Как ограничить выдачу SuggestView конкретным городом, если bounded by не работает, а куда добавить название города (в запрос) я не понимаю. Поисковая строка (SuggestView) у меня сделана отдельным компонентом.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, нужно перед отправкой запроса в геосаджест дополнять текстовую строку нужным городом? var newString='Новосибирск, '+textString

Comment: Это не работает(

Comment: Если не работает, вы или неправильно используете или хотите что-то не то получить. Приведите пример кода, где можно оценить ситуацию в целом.

Comment: SuggestView.events.add("select", function(e: any){
        if (ymaps) {
          ymaps.geocode(`Москва, ${e.get('item').value}`).then((res: any) => {
          const firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
          setAddress(firstGeoObject.getAddressLine());
          setLocation(firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates());
        })}
      })

Comment: Ах ты ж... не заметил, что вы про реакт пишете. Прошу прощения. Тут не помогу. Но вообще без карты положено использовать http-Геосаджест и http-Геокодер, а не выдёргивать отдельные методы из JS API в нарушение пользовательского соглашения. И так вы всегда будете решать самостоятельно, что посылать в сервис.

Comment: Да ничего страшного) А как использовать http-Геосаджест? Есть примеры?